# List custom taxonomies by custom field

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

Below I have my custom taxonomy template and its working fine until now.

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Performer List Page
*/
get_header(); ?>
<?php
// if show all is set
$sortby=$_GET['sortby'];    
if( isset($_GET['showall']) || isset($sortby) ):
$args = array( 'hide_empty' => 0 );
else:
// else show paged
$page = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
global $framework_opt,$post; $number_of_performers = $framework_opt['performers_per_page'];
$orderby = 'date';
$order = isset( $_REQUEST['order'] ) ? trim( $_REQUEST['order'] ) : null;
if(isset($_GET['order']) && !empty($_GET['order'])) {
    switch($order)
{
case 'alphabetically' : $orderby = 'title';
break;
case 'popularity' : $orderby = 'count';
break;      
/*

case 'female' : $meta = 'gazi_female'; 
break;      
case 'male' :   $meta = 'gazi_male';
break;          

*/
default :    $orderby = 'date';
break;
}
}
// number of tags to show per-page
$per_page = $number_of_performers ;
$offset = ( $page-1 ) * $per_page;
$args = array( 'orderby' => $orderby, 'number' => $per_page, 'meta_key' => $meta,  'offset' => $offset, 'hide_empty' => 0 );
endif;
$taxonomy = 'performer';
$count_performers = wp_count_terms( $taxonomy, $offset );
$tax_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );
?>
<aside class="sidebar pull-left">
<p class="sidebar-title"><?php _e( 'SEARCH BY LETTER', 'gazi' ); ?></p>
<div class="letter-search clearfix">
<span class="letter"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>?sortby=A">A</a></span>
<span class="letter"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>?sortby=B">B</a></span>
<span class="letter"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>?sortby=C">C</a></span>
<span class="letter" style="width:40%"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>?showall=true"><?php _e( 'All', 'gazi' ); ?></a></span>
<span class="letter" style="width:40%"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php _e( 'Reset', 'gazi' ); ?></a></span>
</div>

<!--<p class="sidebar-title"><?php _e( 'QUICK SEARCH', 'gazi' ); ?></p>
<form class="frm-search-tag has-title"  action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>" method="get">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search name" name="s" value="" />
<button type="submit"><span class="ico ico-search"></span>
<select class="search_tools" style="display:none;" name="taxonomy" >
    <option value="performer">Videos</option>
    <option value="gallery">Photos</option>                 
</select>
</button>
</form>-->

<div style="height: 5px;"></div>
<?php get_template_part( 'templates/sidebars/performer-sidebar', get_post_format() ); ?>
</aside>
<section class="main-section pull-left">
<div class="page-title with-sorter clearfix">
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

<div class="info hidden-mobile">
    <p>
     <?php echo $count_performers; ?><?php _e( 'Performers', 'gazi' ); ?> <span class="ico ico-tv"></span>
    </p>

    <div class="sorter">
        <div class="dropdown-container">
            <ul class="flyout-menu flyout-menu-right">
                <li>
<button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-action="dropdown-toggle" data-target="#sorter-dropdown">SORT</button>
<div class="flyout-menu-content" id="sorter-dropdown">
<ul class="flyout-menu-items">
<li>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>?order=alphabetically"><?php _e( 'Alphabetically', 'gazi' ); ?></a> </li>
<li>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>?order=popularity"><?php _e( 'Popularity', 'gazi' ); ?></a> </li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div></div> </div>
<div class="info visible-mobile clearfix">
<button class="btn-pd btn-pd-primary pull-left" style="margin-right: 0;" data-action="scroll-to" data-target="#letter-search">A-Z</button>
<p style="float:right">
<?php echo $wp_query->found_posts; ?> <?php _e( 'Performers', 'gazi' ); ?> <span class="ico ico-tv"></span></p>
</div></div>
<div id="performer-list" class="list-view">
<div id="performer-thumbs" class="performer-listing clearfix">
<div class="items">
<?php foreach ($tax_terms as $cat) : ?>
<?php 
$flag = 0; 
if( $sortby == substr( $cat->name, 0, 1 ) || $sortby=='' ) {    $flag = 1;} 
if ($flag=='1'){
?>
<article class="performer-item">
<a class="outline" href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'performer'); ?>" title="<?php echo $cat->name; ?>">  

<?php $performer_image = z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); if(!empty($performer_image)) : ?>

<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/gazi/css/images/1pixel.gif" data-src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id,NULL, array(180, 240)); ?>" alt="<?php echo $cat->name; ?>" />
<noscript><img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id,NULL, array(180, 240)); ?>" alt="<?php echo $cat->name; ?>" /></noscript> 
<?php else : ?>

<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/gazi/css/images/1pixel.gif" data-src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/gazi/css/images/no-img-women.jpg" alt="<?php echo $cat->name; ?>" />
<noscript><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/gazi/css/images/no-img-women.jpg" alt="<?php echo $cat->name; ?>" /></noscript> 
<?php  endif; ?>

<span class="performer-name"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></span>
<span class="performer-videos hidden-mobile">
<span class="count"><?php echo $cat->count; ?></span>
<span class="txt"><?php _e( 'VIDEOS', 'gazi' ); ?></span>
</span>
</a>
<div class="performer-item-footer visible-mobile">
<span class="ico ico-take"></span> <?php echo $cat->count; ?> <?php _e( 'VIDEOS', 'gazi' ); ?> </div>
</article>
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
</div>

<?php
if( isset($_GET['showall']) || isset($sortby)):
    echo '';


else:
// showall is set, show link to get back to paged mode
    $total_terms = wp_count_terms( 'performer' );
    $pages = ceil($total_terms/$per_page);

    // if there's more than one page
    if( $pages > 1 ):
        echo '<div class="pager"><div class="paginator" id="performer_paginator">';

        for ($pagecount=1; $pagecount <= $pages; $pagecount++):
            echo '<a class="page" href="'.get_permalink().'page/'.$pagecount.'/"><span>'.$pagecount.'</span></a>';
        endfor;

        // link to show all
        echo '<a class="page" href="'.get_permalink().'?showall=true">ALL</a>';
echo '</div>';
    endif;


endif;
?>
</div>
<div id="letter-search" class="visible-mobile">
<div class="section-title with-sorter clearfix" style="margin-bottom: 4px;">
<p class="title">Letters Search</p>
<div class="info">
<button class="btn-pd btn-pd-sm btn-pd-primary pull-right" data-action="scroll-to" data-target="#performer-thumbs"><span class="ico ico-grid"></span></button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="letter-search clearfix">
<span class="letter"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>?sortby=A">A</a></span>
<span class="letter"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>?sortby=B">B</a></span>
<span class="letter"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>?sortby=C">C</a></span>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_template_part( 'templates/advertisements_bottom', get_post_format() ); ?>
</section>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

If you see I added an order menu for popularity and videos count for this listing is working but under the order code you will see:

```
/*

case 'female' : $meta = 'gazi_female'; 
break;      
case 'male' :   $meta = 'gazi_male';
break;          

*/
```

so I want to separate performers by male and female using the custom fields above.Any one that has any idea how to complete this template?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You want to show results based on meta field 'gazi_female' or 'gazi_male' so you should include in your meta_query arguments.

Instead of `'meta_key' => $meta` use meta_query. [Meta query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) in get_terms feature got introduced from 4.4.0 version, so make sure your version supports it with get_terms()

You should not use it in order_by parameter since order_by will sort the results and it cant filter results.

Alternatively try [WP_Term_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/) which is available from 4.6 versions

```
// WP_Term_Query arguments
$args = array (
    'taxonomy'               => array( 'performer' ),
    'meta_key'               => 'male',
    'meta_value'             => 'gazi_male',
);

// The Term Query
$term_query = new WP_Term_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( ! empty( $term_query ) && ! is_wp_error( $term_query ) ) {
    // do something
} else {
    // no terms found
}
```

Comment: Hi Lax, yes exactly this is what I want to do, displaying taxonomies as female or male so as you see I have another a-z pagination and Im ordering as popularity etc. but I couldnt figure it out to display also with meta_key, I have last version of wordpress installed

Comment: `'meta_key' => $meta,` is just there this is the reason why Im asking here because didnt work 127.0.0.1/?order=male or female gives empty page without any taxonomy

Comment: Hi @Gazi,I have edited and updated my answer with WP_Term_Query instead of get_terms. Try it and modify it with your other arguments.

Comment: Im gonna check it Lax I will try riht now

Comment: Lax Tankyou for your reply it seems ok I tested in a simple get_terms template btu as I see something wrong when I use it with the terms pagination.As u see my template has offset with a-z and numeric pagination,Thankyou still looking when I get it working I will reply again

Comment: Good to know @Gazi Keep us updated. This will be useful to listing a-z with pagination